# HTML5 canvas not doing what I want with jquery hover() method

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, do-while

So basically I am trying to make a circle that gradually fills in the "border" with a different shade as the user hovers over it.

It works pretty well, but I want it to go away when the user isn't hovering and "restart" at the top of the circle when the user hovers back over it. Instead it continues the while loop regardless of the parameter.

I've tried a couple things including adding a boolean variable called "stop", anding it to the while loop parameters, which does nothing.

All I have on the html is a slightly styled canvas which as you can see by my script has an ID of "wheel1". Here is my JavaScript:

```
var c = document.getElementById("wheel1");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var y = 0;
var stop = false;

var topCircle = function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#AAAAAA";
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

var origCircle = function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#CCCCCC";
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
  topCircle();
}

function hoverEffect(x) {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
    ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, (1.5 + x/1000) * Math.PI, (1.555 + x/1000) * Math.PI);
    ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    topCircle();
  }, (x/2));
}

origCircle();
$('#wheel1').hover(function() {
  stop = false;
  do {
    hoverEffect(y);
    y += 50;
  } 
  while (y <= 2000 && stop == false);
}, function() {
  stop = true;
  y = 0;
  origCircle();
});
```

**EDIT**: Jquery 1.11.3 api is in head and here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Doug021786/dab65vzb/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On hover:**

- Set an `isHovering` flag to true.
- Reset a percent-of-arc-to-draw variable (`pct`) to 0%
- Start an animation loop that increases `pct` from 0% to 100% over time and redraws the arc based on that `pct`.

**On blur:**

- Set an `isHovering` flag to false
- Set a percent-of-arc-to-draw variable (`pct`) to 100% (100% causes any animation to stop).

**Then draw the arc:**

- Clear the canvas,
- Fill the full arc with gray,
- Stroke the full arc with lightgray,
- If the `isHovering` flag is set, stroke the arc in black based on percent-of-arc-to-draw.

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
ctx.lineWidth=12;
ctx.fillStyle='gray';

var PI=Math.PI;
var PI2=PI*2;
var cx=cw/2;
var cy=ch/2;
var radius=Math.min(cx,cy)-ctx.lineWidth/2;
var pct=0;
var pctIncrement=100/60;
var startAngle=-PI/2;
var hoverStyle='black';
var blurStyle='lightgray';
var isHovering=false;

draw()

function draw(){

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  // always draw blur arc
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,startAngle,startAngle+PI2);
  ctx.strokeStyle=blurStyle;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();

  // draw hover arc when hovering
  if(isHovering){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,startAngle,startAngle+PI2*pct/100);
    ctx.strokeStyle=hoverStyle;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

//
function animate(time){

  draw();

  pct+=pctIncrement;
  if(pct>100){pct=100;}

  if(isHovering && pct<=100){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

}

$("#canvas").hover(
  function(){
    isHovering=true;
    pct=0;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  },
  function(){
    isHovering=false;
    pct=100;
    draw();
  }
);
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Hover over the red canvas.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very tricky since you are using a timeout function. Due to this even when you hover off the canvas, hover event is executed and draws the black inner outer circle. One possible way to fix it is to initiate another timeout function which resets the state of the canvas.

```
 function reset() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            origCircle();
        }, 900);
    }

$('#wheel1').hover(
function(){
        stop = false;
     do {
        hoverEffect(y);
        y += 50;
    } 
    while (y <= 2000 && stop == false);
}, function(){
        stop = true;
        y = 0;
        origCircle();
    reset(); 
});
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dab65vzb/2/

Comment: +1 For being on the right track but this doesn't reset it until the circle 'completes'. I'm playing around with what you came up with and I am going to see if there is some different way to execute your reset function so it does what I want it to. 

Do you think there's a more elegant overall solution than setTimeout to initiate hoverEffect()?